# PHP wampserver process page

Tags: php, mysqli

How do i fix this error to create my process page to move to the next question on my database:
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\quiz\process.php on line 32

```
<?php 
//check to see if score is set_error_handler
if (!isset($_SESSION['score'])) {
    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
}

if ($_POST) {
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $selected_choice = $_POST['option'];
    $next = $number++;

/*
* Get total questions
*/
$query = "SELECT * FROM questions";

//Get result 
$results = $mysqli->query($query);
$total = $results->num_rows;

/*
* Get correct option
*/
$query = 'SELECT * FROM options WHERE WHERE question_no = $number AND is_correct = 1';
// Get result
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

// Get row

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

//Set correct choice

$correct_choice = $row['id'];

//Compare
if ($correct_choice == $selected_choice) {
    //Answer is correct
    $_SESSION['score']++;
```

Comment: your code failed. get the real error

Comment: your code is throwing error.Please refer [this](http://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/mysql_fetch_assoc.php) for getting better idea about mysqli_fetch_assoc()

Comment: SELECT * FROM options WHERE WHERE ... One WHERE  too many. Your query probably fails and you don't check if there are any results coming back.

Comment: @Gerard thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Check the ****Changed Line**** below. Use fetch_assoc instead of mysqli_fetch_assoc

```
/*
* Get total questions
*/
$query = "SELECT * FROM questions";

//Get result 
$results = $mysqli->query($query);
$total = $results->num_rows;

/*
* Get correct option
*/
$query = 'SELECT * FROM options WHERE WHERE question_no = $number AND is_correct = 1';
// Get result
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

// Get row

$row = $result->mysqli_fetch_assoc(); // ****Changed Line****

//Set correct choice

$correct_choice = $row['id'];

//Compare
if ($correct_choice == $selected_choice) {
    //Answer is correct
    $_SESSION['score']++;
```

Comment: i've tried fetch_assoc(); alone and yet the complain is still the same

Comment: Hi. did you try the mysqli_fetch_assoc() ?